# How to encrypt password in ExpressJS

Tags: express

Current I tried to create authentication controller for my app.

But I just use plain password.

Can u help me a good package to do it. With a tuts then best.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

You can follow this ebook: https://www.udemy.com/nodejs-master-class/